# Pyspark column convert a string which has both positive and negative numbers

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, casting

I have a pysapark column which is of string data type. But it has both positive and negative numbers. How do I convert them as digits.

total amount = Volume * price_perunit
Currently Volume = String, price_perunit = double
Expectedoutput:

```
Volume     price_perunit     total amount
-0.75      100                -75
  8        100                 800
 -0.01     8                   -0.08
```

Right now, when I multiply, I get the following results which is wrong as the negative sign is no longer available.

```
Volume     price_perunit     total amount
-0.75      100                75
  8        100                 800
 -0.01     8                   0.08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just casting.

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Volume: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price_perunit: double (nullable = true)


df.withColumn('Volume', col('Volume').cast('double')) \
  .withColumn('total amount', expr('Volume * price_perunit')) \
  .show()

+------+-------------+------------+
|Volume|price_perunit|total amount|
+------+-------------+------------+
| -0.75|          100|       -75.0|
|   8.0|          100|       800.0|
| -0.01|            8|       -0.08|
+------+-------------+------------+
```